# Como extrair dados do excell para Gerar gráficos?

Tags: php, javascript, html, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela de excell com 50 linhas e 10 colunas, contendo dados alunos inscritos em um concurso. Tenho de criar gráficos a partir destes dados. Alguém poderia sugerir uma forma de extrair e trabalhar esses dados em html e javascrit ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma boa opção é usar o [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).
Usa javascript puro, mas se vc quiser pode associar jQuery para facilitar a manipulação dos objetos na página.
Veja aqui exemplos de [mapas básicos](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery#basic-charts).
Vc pode trabalhar com a sua planilha em excel, salvar com CSV e usar no d3js.
Vc só copia o código javascript na sua pagina, cria um stage (uma div por exemplo) e salva o arquivo CSV dentro de uma pasta do seu projeto. e mais nada.
O d3 vai criar o restante para vc.